# Why is 'id' called 'sub' in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Im looking at the new Keycloak Beta 4 API. When i get the users account information, what is referred to as 'id' in the web ui comes back as 'sub' in the account object.

```
{ sub: '25a37fd0-d10e-40ca-af6c-821f20e01be8',
  name: 'Barrack Obama',
  preferred_username: 'obama@whitehouse.gov',
  given_name: 'Barrack',
  family_name: 'Obama',
  email: 'obama@whitehouse.gov' }
```

What is 'sub' and is this a safe uuid to map database objects to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the keycloak documentation

**Anatomy of Action Token**

Action token is a standard Json Web Token signed with active realm key where the payload contains several fields:

```
typ - Identification of the action (e.g. verify-email)

iat and exp - Times of token validity

sub - ID of the user

azp - Client name

iss - Issuer - URL of the issuing realm

aud - Audience - list containing URL of the issuing realm

asid - ID of the authentication session (optional)

nonce - Random nonce to guarantee uniqueness of use if the operation can only be executed once (optional)
```

Please refer the following link https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_action_token_anatomy

Reason may be they want to retain the uniqueness in the name.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the previous answer, inside JWT tokens, `sub` refers to `subject.` The reason is that those tokens can be used in various cases, including authorization. That means that `id` sometimes might not be "the unique identifier" but might be anything, including repeatable destinations. Basically, a naming convention JWT follows, regardless of Keycloak.